# What are these objects near Mirach

Tags: star, amateur-observing

Night sky objects always interested me, nowadays Im trying to observe and photograph some of these objects. My phone is iPhone 6S, i used SkyGuide app to find positions, NightCap to photograph. Im sure brightest star is Mirach according to SkyGuide app.

It's photographed at 00:30 at my local time (Istanbul, London + 3), SkyGuide says Mirach's azimuth was 77° 11’ 28” .

[image: What are those?]

Comment: For questions like this one it would always help us to give you an answer, if you also provide such information like the local time of your photo or the azimuth direction in which your object was visible.

Comment: Sorry, Im editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is really Mirach, then I would say the point-like object above and a little to the left of it is the star mu And (another designation: 37 And) in the same constellation of Andromeda. Then the next point-like object slightly further above and to the left from mu And would be the star nu And (35 And). And a barely visible fuzzy object above nu And would be the Andromeda galaxy (M31). Then in the left lower corner we see another star Nembus (51 And), and above it the star phi And (42 And). And at the same height with nu And farther to the right from it at the edge of the building there is the star pi And (29 And).

I would strongly suggest you to use Stellarium (www.stellarium.org) for identification of nearly any night sky object visible at your or any other location on Earth at any time.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer, I got Stellarium on my laptop, but I found it a little bit complicated, Im reading guides though.